# Measure theory question (not sure what else to title it)

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have $\mu$ which is a measure on the $\sigma-$ring $S$,

Suppose $E\in S$ and $E$ is of $\sigma-$finite measure.

Let $C$ be a class of (pairwise) disjoint sets.

Then $\mu(E\cap D)\ne 0$ for at most countably many $D\in C$.

I am not sure where to begin with this. I think the question can be re-phrased as "$E$ can be covered by at most countably many disjoint sets" as $E$ is $\sigma-$finite, I know there's a family of sets $\{A_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ - each of finite measure, such that $E\subset\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

Comment: Hint: First assume that μ(E) is finite and bound the number of Ds in C such that μ(E∩D) is at least 1/n, for every n. Conclude in this case, then treat the general case where μ(E) can be infinite.

Comment: @Did you sound like the book I'm reading! With that hint and like 5 sheets of scribbles later I'm still not sure. In the finite case, I can say "well summing up the overlap must be $\le$ than the measure of E itself" but in the infinite case I am not sure. Either way I'm not confident with proceeding.

Comment: Did you manage to bound the number of Ds in C such that μ(E∩D) is at least 1/n, for every n, when μ(E) is finite, say, μ(E)=K?

Comment: @Did yes, if we assume E is finite (call it's measure $m$) then there are at most $nm$ (taking the integer value of this) things in the set.

Comment: @Did because each one is $\ge\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: That was the first step of my first comment. Now to the second step.

Comment: @Did that's the hard part! Which is where I am stuck.

Comment: @Did bump ( - there are no solutions in the back of the book, I am truly stuck!)

Comment: Write $E$ as a countable union of sets of finite measure, $E=\cup_{i\in\Bbb N} E_i$. If $E$ has non-empty intersection with uncountably many $D$, then at least one $E_i$ has ...

Comment: I don't follow the "uncountably man" part - 2 of you clearly know how to do this, why so reluctant to give an answer today? I'm reading a book - this'd be a good time to give an answer (Halmos - Measure Theory - Q4 p 31)

Comment: @DavidMitra ....

Comment: ... non-empty intersection with uncountably many $D$. This can't happen from the first part we did.

Comment: But you only know $E\subset\cup E_i$ from $\sigma-$finite. @DavidMitra

Comment: @DavidMitra how you you just "suppose it's uncountable" - how do you express that?

Comment: @DavidMitra when I study a book alone I will get no feedback at all, if I'm lucky it'll have answers in the back and I can follow them. When this isn't the case (like now) I have no way to know if I "wrote it out" correctly. I wont get any confirmation ever, and in areas where my confidence is iffy I want to have a model answer to justify mine off. Like here, I'm dealing with uncountably many things and have to make a leap from the given hint (in the book) of assuming finite, to just assuming $\sigma-$finite, please please answer this, I want to be confident I am right.

Comment: @Did same goes for you! If either of you two have the book, a look at question 2 would be nice (finite implies sigma finite, so I'm not sure what the question wants)

Comment: "way to know if I "wrote it out" correctly" + "have a model answer to justify [my answer] off": If this is your goal, the first thing to do is to SHOW what you "wrote out" + "your answer". How come that, so far, you showed ZERO of this?

Comment: @Did I can do the easy part (use the hint and assume E is measurable) as I said the book gives me the hint, I get scared venturing into the uncountable. In return I get shown this total lack of trust "oh this might be homework" screw that, perhaps someone is learning measure theory solo and comes here for the odd nudge! It's holding me back and it's hurtful - worst thing is that this protest probably makes it less likely I'll ever get help.

Comment: Which part of "show what you did" do you fail to understand? Yes, the fact that you steadfastly refuse to show anything you did, even after you have been asked to do so, probably influences the view at least some users of the site have of your approach of the site.

Comment: @Did I have gotten as far as the finite case! Want me to edit the two lines of reasoning into the post? If E has finite measure the 1/n hint in the book is more than enough! It's the uncountable case I am iffy with.

Comment: @Did the first part is as the hint says, assume it is finite and define a class where the measure of the intersection is greater than 1/n, because the measure of E is say m, you know there are at most mn things in the class, which is countable.

Comment: @Did is it worth adding those 2 sentences?

Answer (score 1):

So, you know there are sets $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots$, each of finite measure, so that $E\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i$.

Since each $A_i$ has finite measure, it follows from the first step you made, as alluded to in the comments, that for each $i\in\Bbb N$, the set $$B_i=\{ D\in C: |D\cap A_i|>0\}$$ is countable.

Now if $D\in C$ and $|D\cap E|>0$, it follows that there is an $i\in\Bbb N$ with $|D\cap A_i|>0$. Indeed, if $|D\cap A_i|=0$ for every $i\in\Bbb N$, Then $$|D\cap E|\le \Bigl| D\cap\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N}A_i\Bigr|
=\Bigl|\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} (D\cap A_i)\Bigr|
\le\sum_{i=1}^\infty|D\cap A_i|=0.$$

So, we know  that if $D\in C$ and $|D\cap E|>0$, then $D\in B_i$ for some $i$; that is, $D\in\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N} B_i$.
It follows from this, and the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable, that the set $\{D\in C: |D\cap E|>0\}$ is countable.

Comment: Love the bit where you show using contrapositive there's an $i\in\mathbb{N}$, that was a bit I was confused on. I'm still not totally happy with the last last 2 lines. I am happy with countable union of countable sets is countable - are you saying that the set on the last line is a subset of $\cup^\infty_{n=1}B_i$? this is the bit I am unsure of. I get the logic!

Comment: Wait, being silly, you've shown that $D\in C$ with $\mu(D\cap E)\ne 0$ $\implies$ $D\in\cup^\infty_{n=1}B_n$, and implies is basically a subset relation (??? - what is this stated formally) and that's how the result follows. Right?

Comment: @AlecTeal $B_i$ is a collection of sets (elements of $C$), so $\cup_{i\in\Bbb N} B_i$ is a collection of sets (elements of $C$). It's just saying $D$ is one of those sets. So, the set of all $D\in C$ with $|D\cap E|>0$ is a subset of the countable set $\cup_{i\in\Bbb N} B_i$.

Comment: Yeah, the subset relation there is just "not obvious" (showing it set-wise would be difficult and tedious, but the $D\in C$ with $\mu(D\cap E)\ne0$ $\implies$ $D\in\cup B_i$ shows the subset relation!)